# Disable reachability block from functioning while specific View Controllers are Loaded?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, reachability

I am using **[Reachability](https://github.com/tonymillion/Reachability)** Block by tonymillionon applicationDidFinishedLaunching and that it shows a pop up over View. But out of many ViewControllers there are some ViewControllers where downloaded data is placed and there is no need of Internet. So, i want that the Block Code Does not work there? Is there any proper way of doing it?

Answer (score 1):

The best way depends on the structure of your classes and which class is monitoring the reachability. Because the reachability is a common task and can be interacted with from anywhere using notifications is suitable. Define 2 notifications, 1 for reachability not required and the other for reachability required. In your view controllers that want to disable reachability monitoring post the notifications in`viewDidAppear` and `viewWillDisappear` respectively. When the notifications are received you can set a flag so the reachability block suppresses the alert or just nil the callback block.